# SSH socks proxy reverse connection Connection denied

Tags: ssh, reverse-proxy, ssh-tunnel, socks

So I wrote a java app that connects to a server in a reverse way (-R) and creates a ssh server where it is executed so the server can execute commands in the client that executed my app. That part work perfectly. The problem is that I want to create a SOCKS proxy in the server and tunnelize the traffic through the client.
The command I am using is:

`ssh -vvv -f -D 0.0.0.0:8080 localhost -p 11707 -N`

I am receiving this error:

```
debug1: Connection to port 8080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug2: fd 5 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug2: channel 1: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 1: pre_dynamic: have 4
debug2: channel 1: decode socks5
debug2: channel 1: socks5 auth done
debug2: channel 1: pre_dynamic: need more
debug2: channel 1: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 1: pre_dynamic: have 25
debug2: channel 1: decode socks5
debug2: channel 1: socks5 post auth
debug2: channel 1: dynamic request: socks5 host www.cualesmiip.com port 80 command 1
channel 1: open failed: administratively prohibited: Connection denied
debug2: channel 1: zombie
debug2: channel 1: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 1: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 8080 for www.cualesmiip.com port 80, connect from 4.174.29.15 port 50879, nchannels 2
debug3: channel 1: status: The following connections are open:
```

I have `AllowTcpForwarding` set to `yes` in the ssh server that is receiving the connections.

Where can be the error??
Thank you

Answer (score -2):

Set the GatewayPorts option to yes within the sshd_config.

GatewayPorts yes

Comment: I don't think `GatewayPorts` in `sshd_config` has any influence on the behavior of `-D`.